# Vue multiple properties inside mustaches

Tags: vue.js

Is it possible to place multiple properties inside mustaches (curly brackets)?

All below code wont work properly (assume first and second are string/integer):

```
<p>Using mustaches: {{ first,second }}</p>
<p>Using mustaches: {{ first second }}</p>
<p>Using mustaches: {{ first+second }}</p>
```

It works using more mustaches:

```
<p>Using mustaches: {{ first }},{{ second }}</p>
```

Comment: Can't see why `first+second` wouldn't work

Comment: sorry, i have edited, they got sum up if they are integers

Comment: Only the `{{ first second }}` doesn't _work_ because it isn't a valid JS expression. `{{ first, second }}` ignores the second expression because the interpolator only looks for a single expression. What is your actual question?

Comment: Why would you not expect summing integers to not sum integers?

Comment: using {{ first }},{{ second }} before, but dont feel right. I thought the data is string at first so I try to use +, and summing up is not what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contents are just an expression. It's pretty much just normal JavaScript but with identifiers scoped to `this` and support for Vue filters tagged on the end.

e.g.

```html
<p>{{ first + second }}</p>
<p>{{ first + ' ' + second }}</p>
<p>{{ first + ' comes before ' + second }}</p>
<p>{{ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 }}</p>
<p>{{ methodCall(first, second) }}</p>
<p>{{ first || second || 'none' }}</p>
<p>{{ first | formatWithAFilter }}</p>
```

If the expression evaluates to a primitive (strings, numbers, etc.) it will be output using the usual string representation. `null` and `undefined` are treated like empty strings (similar to Array `join`). For an object it will be dumped out as JSON, which can be useful for debugging.

Comment: Can even use template literals, eg `{{ \`${first},${second}\` }}`

Comment: `{{ \`${first},${second}\` }}` and `{{ first + ' ' + second }}` works well if i want to print two integers separately.